# TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined when accessing the props

Tags: reactjs

After passing the props from one component to another component I'm able to access the props using

```
console.log(this.findArrayElementByEdit(this.props.edituser))
```

but I'm getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined when I try to access the age element using

```
  console.log(this.findArrayElementByEdit(this.props.edituser)[0].age)
```

This is the findArrayElementByEdit() method.

```
 findArrayElementByEdit(array) {
    return array.filter((element) => {
      return element.isEdit === true;
    })
  }
```

Comment: You need to handle the situation where `findArrayElementByEdit` returns an empty array. It will not have an element at index `[0]`. What do you want to do if no items with `isEdit` equal to `true`?

Comment: We can check the length of the response and if the length>0 then we can output the array element